# Run Docker "Chrome Selenium Webdriver" image on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, docker, selenium, raspberry-pi

Using Python, I'm trying to run a Google Chrome Webdriver on Raspberry PI 3B (Debian 10).

I wrote a script that can do it and it works well. Now, I want to run a Docker image of this script.

My script:

```
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opts.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts, 
                          executable_path=chrome_webdriver_path)  
driver.get("https://google.com/") 
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Unfortunately, I got an error when I'm trying to run this code with docker because I can't found the binaries of the google-chrome web driver. In Raspberry PI 3B, these binaries as located in :

"/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"

I tried to install google-chrome-stable, but it doesn't fit the with the Raspberry Pi.

Finally, my DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.7

# Set workspace
WORKDIR /app

# Install python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

# Copy local files
COPY . .

RUN python main.py
```

I run my docker code in a folder with the script and a DOCKERFILE above
"docker build -t image_name ."

Do you know how to manage this?

PS: Don't want to switch to Firefox or use a remote Webdriver.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install headless chrome in your docker container when it runs? You need to have a headless chrome which matches your selenium chrome webdriver.

Comment: Yeah, in my options -> opts. And it works running "python main.py"

Comment: No, what you set in options are the webdriver path, not the headless chrome. you have to have headless chrome installed, which is totally different from chrome webdriver. 

The way selenium works is using webdriver as a bridge between your application and real web browser. In your case, the real web browser is the headless chrome you are missing. Webdriver is just a bridge to forward your browsing data between real browser and your application.  The real work is done in chrome, either a real chrome browser or a headless chrome browser.

Comment: Well, I tried to download google-chrome-stable and google-standalone into my docker container but it didn't work. So I thought I just need to pass ("--headless") option